# Matrix x vector

Tags: matrices, vectors

[matrix x vector multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZucD.png)

Are these correct? When I calculated them I got -2,1,3 for the first and 1,0,-2 for the second. if I am incorrect, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results you have shown in the linked image and the question text do not match. The correct values are

a) $$ \left| \matrix{ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} \right| 
\pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ 3} = \pmatrix{(-1)(2) \\ (1)(1) \\ (1)(3)} = \pmatrix{-2 \\ 1 \\ 3} \;\;\checkmark$$

b) $$ \left| \matrix{ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} \right| 
\pmatrix{0 \\ -1 \\ -2} = \pmatrix{(-1)(-1) \\ (1)(0) \\ (1)(-2)} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ -2} \;\;\checkmark$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you did a mistake on the picture on the last rows (either on matrix A) or on both of your calculation, as $1*3 \neq -3$ and $1*(-2) \neq 2$. Else, you are correct.